# How to redirect using rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to use rewrite rules to redirect as such:
https://myurl.com/w2/clientname.w2
to
https://myurl.com/clientname

The client name is not static. It can be anything.

I am not sure whether I can do this using just rewrite rules or whether I also need to use rewrite maps?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a rewrite rule using a regular expression. For your example something like `w2/(.*)\.w2` could be the pattern and that should get you "clientname" as `{R:1}` to use in your redirect.